# How to Filter by distinct field value in Django? Cannot use distinct() function because of Mysql database

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework

I have a customer group table

```
class customerGroupMaster(models.Model):

    customer_group_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    customer_group_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey(customerMaster, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I want to filter the queryset by unique customer_group_id field in the ListAPIView class.

```
class customerGroupNameFilter(generics.ListAPIView):
  
   # queryset = customerGroupMaster.objects.annotate(num_of_group=Count('customer_group_name', distinct=True))
    # this line needs to edited to get the expected output
    serializer_class = customerGroupMasterSerializers
    permissions_class = [IsAuthenticated]
```

So for exapmle:

Customer group table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLpuk.png)

After filter(expected output):
Customer group table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCgub.png)

Comment: Please format your questuion properly

Comment: Is the format correct now?@JPG

Comment: Note that you wouldn't normally store group name in such a table - and you've not provided the criteria for choosing one row over another.

Comment: @Strawberry I couldn't really understand your concern. Basically I want to implement the group by customer_group_id sql statement in my customerGroupNameFilter class?

Comment: You want to return one row in each group, but you don't say which one, and why.

Comment: @Strawberry Any row will work. All I need is the list of unique group names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `.values(...)` method and it should work.

```
queryset = customerGroupMaster.objects.values('customer_group_name').annotate(num_of_group=Count('customer_group_name', distinct=True))
```